# inotify C headers

Tags: c, linux, header, inotify

So I'm trying to write a C program that uses inotify. I've used pyinotify before so I understand how it works. However, I'm following some guide and it tells me to include `<linux/inotify.h>`. The problem is that this header only has macro definitions, not the funciton prototypes. It looks like the functions are prototyped in `<sys/inotify.h>`.

My question is what's the difference between `linux/inotify.h` and `sys/inotify.h`? Why are there both?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sys/inotify.h` is part of the [GNU C library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library). It exposes the structures and functions that your program will use in order to receive filesystem change notifications. It can be considered as the public API of the notification system.

`linux/inotify.h` is part of the Linux kernel. It defines the kernel structures and constants used to implement the notification system itself. You shouldn't include that file unless you're writing something like a kernel module, because it's Linux-specific and thus not portable.

Comment: sys/inotify.h is not part of the standard library! (It is, however, part of the libraries typically available on a linux box)

Comment: @Billy, my `sys/inotify.h` says `This file is part of the GNU C library` right in the top of the file, and my package manager says it's installed by `glibc`. What does yours say?

Comment: @Frédéric: GNU C Library != Standard Library. Standard Library == `ISO/IEC 9899:1990` or `ISO/IEC 9899:1999`.

Comment: @Billy, `glibc` is an implementation of the standard library defined in the ISO standards you're citing. What's the problem? :)

Comment: Sure, but not all of glibc belongs to the standard. This is one of those bits.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: Glibc contains **tons** of GNU and POSIX specific stuff -- namely *anything* in the "sys/" folder for headers, "unistd.h", stuff for sockets... etc. The standard library is only `assert.h`, `ctype.h`, `errno.h`, `float.h`, `iso646.h`, `limits.h`, `locale.h`, `math.h`, `setjmp.h`, `signal.h`, `stdarg.h`, `stddef.h`, `stdio.h`, `stdlib.h`, `string.h`, and `time.h`. (Well a few things were added in C99 but I don't have that list ATM..)

Comment: @Billy, @Ignacio, thanks for the clarification, I'll add `GNU` to my answer then :)

Comment: To echo GNU != POSIX, BSD does not have `inotify` as the functionality is in `kqueue`. For portability, try http://mark.heily.com/pnotify/